# passing UDF to a method or class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF say

```
val testUDF = udf{s: string=>s.toUpperCase}
```

I want to create this UDF in a separate method or may be something else like an implementation class and pass it on another class which uses it. Is it possible?

Say suppose I have a class A

```
class A(df: DataFrame) {
    def testMethod(): DataFrame = {
        val demo=df.select(testUDF(col))
    }
}
```

class A should be able to use UDF. Can this be achieved?

Comment: yes definitely possible :)

Comment: Are you asking how to create a UDF from a function in a method? how to create a UDF for a generic function? how to pass it to testMethod? what would be the end goal?

Comment: Have you decided to accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Given a `dataframe` as

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|abc |
|dBf |
|Aec |
+----+
```

And a `udf` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val testUDF = udf{s: String=>s.toUpperCase}
```

You can definitely use that `udf` function from another class as

```
val demo = df.select(testUDF(col("col1")).as("upperCasedCol"))
```

which should give you

```
+-------------+
|upperCasedCol|
+-------------+
|ABC          |
|DBF          |
|AEC          |
+-------------+
```

But I would suggest you to use [other functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) if possible **as udf function requires columns to be serialized and deserialized which would consume time and memory more than other functions available. UDF function should be the last choice**.

You can use [upper function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#upper(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) for your case

```
 val demo = df.select(upper(col("col1")).as("upperCasedCol"))
```

This will generate the same output as the original `udf` function

I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

Since your question is asking for information on how to call the udf function defined in another class or object, here is the method

suppose you have an object where you defined the udf function or a function that i suggested as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object UDFs {

  def testUDF = udf{s: String=>s.toUpperCase}

  def testUpper(column: Column) = upper(column)
}
```

Your A class is as in your question, I just added  another function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

class A(df: DataFrame) {
  def testMethod(): DataFrame = {
    val demo = df.select(UDFs.testUDF(col("col1")))
    demo
  }

  def usingUpper() = {
    df.select(UDFs.testUpper(col("col1")))
  }
}
```

Then you can call the functions from main as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object TestUpper {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application")
      .master("local")
      .config("", "")
      .getOrCreate()
    import sparkSession.implicits._

    val df = Seq(
      ("abc"),
      ("dBf"),
      ("Aec")
    ).toDF("col1")

    val a = new A(df)
    //calling udf function
    a.testMethod().show(false)

    //calling upper function
    a.usingUpper().show(false)
  }
}
```

I guess this is more than helpful

Comment: isn't the answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would actually like some kind of factory to create this `user-defined-function` for a specific class A.
This could be achieve using a type class which gets injected implicitly.

E.g. (I had to define UDF and DataFrame to be able to test this)

```
type UDF = String => String

case class DataFrame(col: String) {
  def select(in: String) = s"col:$col, in:$in"
}

trait UDFFactory[A] {
  def testUDF: UDF
}
implicit object UDFFactoryA extends UDFFactory[AClass] {
  def testUDF: UDF = _.toUpperCase
}

class AClass(df: DataFrame) {
  def testMethod(implicit factory: UDFFactory[AClass]) = {
    val demo = df.select(factory.testUDF(df.col))
    println(demo)
  }
}

val a = new AClass(DataFrame("test"))
a.testMethod // prints 'col:test, in:TEST'
```

Comment: Is there a way I can pass UDF to a class.. say for example in your example, AClass will have two parameters Aclass(df, UDF)

Comment: @KishoreKumar yes, `class Aclass(df: DataFrame, myUDF: UserDefinedFunction)`

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, create a method exactly like your UDF in your object body or companion class,

```
val myUDF = udf((str:String) => { str.toUpperCase })
```

Then for some dataframe `df` do this,

```
val res=df withColumn("NEWCOLNAME", myUDF(col("OLDCOLNAME")))
```

This will change something like this,

```
+-------------------+
|     OLDCOLNAME    |
+-------------------+
|        abc        |
+-------------------+
```

to

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|     OLDCOLNAME    |     NEWCOLNAME    |
+-------------------+-------------------+
|        abc        |        ABC        | 
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Let me know if this helped, Cheers.

Comment: myUDF is missing the udf method call (and type modifier). You defined a regular function...

Comment: Ya i had map in mind when i wrote that. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats possible as functions are objects in scala which can be passed around:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

class A(df: DataFrame, testUdf:UserDefinedFunction) {    
    def testMethod(): DataFrame = {
        df.select(testUdf(col))
    }
}
```